# "It was a really, really big lie that John told." Is this a correct usage?

Tags: phrase-usage

A speaker might say things like -

> It was a really, really big lie that John told.

Is this a correct usage?

Comment: What part of the sentence is unclear?

Comment: It's fairly idiomatic.

Comment: Shakespeare uses 'A little, little grave' (perhaps without the comma) in _Richard II_.  And Wild, in _For a Few Dollars More_, in response to Col. Mortimer's  'It's a small world', responds 'Yes, and very, very bad.' Whereupon Mortimer (Lee Van Cleef) shoots him. Possibly not because of the 'very, very' construction.

Comment: This posting has been bled dry through over-zealous editing done in an attempt to render it less controversial, and the result no longer bears any resemblance to the original intent.

Answer (score 1):

Repetition of the adverb for emphasis may be effective on occasion, but I saw the original post, and I think [this quote](http://www.shadesofcrimson.com/2011/01/25/editing-with-adverbs/) is suitable.

> Adverbs...when used excessively.....[the writing] takes on an overly dramatic tone, perhaps even sounding preachy...leads to redundant phrasing and the appearance of a writer **whose repertoire is lacking.**

I think this fits the situation and the source of the quote.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically correct. There's nothing nothing wrong with repeating a word for emphasis, especially in conversation. However, in formal writing it may be more appropriate to write directly: "John told a really big lie."